# The JavaScript 'clearInterval' function does not appear to be working. Can anyone help me?

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I have the following code which adjusts the size of two panels, one above the other. Move the mouse up and the top panel will get smaller while the bottom panel will get larger. It all seems to work well enough, however, on  mouseup although the 'clearInterval' line appears to be executed, 'interval' is not reset and movement of the mouse still alters the panel sizes.

Can anyone point out where I have gone wrong or indeed indicate a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(event){
  document.querySelector('#partition').onmousedown = function(event){
    //Set a timer to check every millisecond the position of the mouse and asign that position to the panels
    var interval=setInterval(function(){
      onmousemove = function(e){
        document.getElementById('topPanel').style.height = e.clientY;
        document.getElementById('btmPanel').style.height = viewport_height - e.clientY - 10;
      }
      //check for mouse up and cancel timer.
      onmouseup = function(){
        clearInterval(interval); 
      }
    }, 100); // the above code is executed every 100 ms  
  }
});
```

Comment: You’re assigning an event handler to `onmousemove` that’ll get called every time the mouse moves. `setInterval` doesn’t do anything here (especially not what the comment says); what you should find out how to do is remove an event handler.

Comment: *"although the 'clearInterval' line appears to be executed"*: what made you think that? It is not.

Comment: Unclear how you expect `onmousemove` and `onmouseup` to be called. You do not seem to be binding them to an element. Every 100ms you are creating to functions. I do not think that is what you want.

Comment: Right.  That code doesn't do what you think it does.  When the mouse is clicked, you then have a function called 10 times a second.  That function tries to install a mousemove handler and a mouse up handler (again, 10 times a second, although all you're really doing is creating variables called `onmousemove` and `onmouseup`).  You need to decide, do you want to handle mouse motion messages, or do you want to go query the mouse position 10 times per second?